# Laravel 4.2 -> Pass a variable containing array to Theme partial or layouts

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function about(){
    $tempPageID = Input::get('page_id');
    $pageLayout = DB::table('tbl_page')->where('id',$tempPageID)->first();
         $data = array(
            'page' => $pageLayout
         );
    $layout = $pageLayout->page_layout;
    $theme = Theme::uses('homepage')->layout('default',$data);
    return $theme->of('layouts/'.$layout,$data)->render();
}
```

This my code in my HomeController that calls the page about. the thing is the first division of my page is only included in the layout 'default.blade.php' which is {{ Theme::partial('bannerForm') }}

I'm trying to make the content of the whole page dynamic but cant do it because I cant pass the $data to the bannerForm.blade.php the error is Undefined variable: page .

Does anyone encountered this problem? What can I do to make this work? My second plan is to put the whole bannerForm code in the layout 'default.blade.php' to make it simple but still the same error. Unlike the last line of code which works fine.

Comment: did you tried Viewcomposers? i dont know what you are trying to do but from the title first thing that comes to my mind is Viewcomposers that allows you to send data to multiple Views/partials always

Comment: I already fixed my problem using a simple $_POST and ifCondition. But I will take note about your recommendation.

Comment: then close the question or answer it

Comment: I tried other work around and learned about Request::segment(2); I passed a data in the url then get it using segment then used it for my database query.